# Create a snapshot of the Mapbox mapview on iOS?

Tags: ios, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I am using the Mapbox iOS SDK (2.1.2) and I want to create a snapshot of the mapview.  I can see where this is possible using the 1.x.x version of the iOS SDK, but I do not see any method in the current API.  I searched the Mapbox Github repo but I did not see anything there.  I also dropped a message on their support page but I haven't heard back.

If a suitable method does not yet exist in the API, can someone suggest a workaround? Or could someone suggest where I would start in adding the functionality myself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Updated answer:** Mapbox Maps SDK for iOS 3.7.0+ includes [`MGLMapSnapshotter`](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.7.3/Classes/MGLMapSnapshotter.html), which will get you a rasterized map without a map view — see [this example](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/map-snapshotter/) for a basic implementation.

*Old answer kept below, for the sake of posterity...*

---

There isn’t a snapshot method in `MGLMapView` yet, [but one is planned](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/1701).

In the meantime, these will get you the contents of the map view (and only that map view), including the base map and the map UI:

**Objective-C**:

```
- (UIImage *)snapshot:(UIView *)view {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, YES, 0);
    [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage *snapshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return snapshot;
}
```

**Swift**:

```
func snapshot(view: UIView) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, true, 0)
    view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let snapshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return snapshot
}
```

[image: Map snapshot]

Comment: Great great answer! Thank you fried rabbit!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking for method in Mapbox API you can write your own implementation to capture contents of the mapview. You can try this out.

```
-(UIImage*)mapToImage{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mapView.bounds.size);
    [mapView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *mapImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return mapImage;
}
```

Comment: This code is resulting in an image with the Mapbox annotation and the info button, both rendered at position (0,0), but none of the vector graphics tiles are appearing.